# C# Add property to a list of objects

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket

I have a list of objects : `{ "name":"John", "birth":"1986-12-14", "city":"New York"}`

I try to send this list through a websocket, but what am I missing is a `"msg_code"` property, It would look like :

`{ "msg_code": "ListUsers", "name":"John", "birth":"1986-12-14", "city":"New York"}`

How can I append msg_code to a list of objects?

```
            var users = LoadUsers(); // List of Users ({ "name":"John", "birth":"1986-12-14", "city":"New York"}) etc..
            string output = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(users);
            session.Send(output);
```

Edit :
[image]

Trying to give msg_code property to users list :

```
        private static void HandleViewUsers(WebSocketSession session)
        {
            var users = LoadUsers();
            string output = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(users);
            output['msg_code'] = 'ListUsers'; // error
            session.Send(output);
        }
```

Comment: Example: `let myvar = { "name":"John", "birth":"1986-12-14", "city":"New York"}`, Inserting the `'msg_core'` object: `myvar['msg_core'] = "ListUsers"`

Comment: I am trying to apply this on ```var users``` but it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Edit your topic and post what you tried to do and show what you’re getting

Comment: Right after `var users` try: `for(let i in users) { users[i]['msg_code'] = 'ListUsers' }`

Comment: compilation problem, its C#

Comment: I just noticed that your code is in java and not in javascript as you put it in your question tag. Java is different from javascript

Comment: is there any way to make it work? Its C# asp.net

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#, you should have used the `C#` tag in your question

Comment: Try `Serialize(users.Select(u => new {u.id, u.name, u.surname, msg_code = "ListUsers" }))`

Comment: Don't use `JavaScriptSerializer` class but use System.Text.Json. Much way better and faster

Comment: @Kalten It works but instead of giving msg_code property to every object in this list id like to give 1 property msg_code for the whole list. Is that possible? Please help

Comment: @Simonsoft177 You can't add a field to a list in json. But You can wrap the list in another objet that will contains both list and msg_code. `.Serialize(new { users, msg_code = "ListUsers"})`

Answer (score 2):

To insert a new object, just pass the key of the object and the value to it. Example:

```js
let myObj = { "name":"John", "birth":"1986-12-14", "city":"New York"}

console.log(myObj)

myObj['msg_code'] = 'listUsers'

console.log(myObj)
```

Comment: Use a loop to cycle through the entire object, and apply the idea above

Comment: How about only one msg_code for a list of objects? So its like object inside objects inside object ```{msg_code : "ListUsers"`}{ '"name":"Danny", "birth":"1926-22-24", "city":"New York"} , { "name":"John", "birth":"1986-12-14", "city":"Los Angeles"'}```

Comment: Add an example of the object you hope to obtain

Comment: I have edited my post, I have a list of users and I want to append a msg_code property to this list of objects like on printscreen

Comment: I get compilation problems with this code, with ```let``` its C#